# QGIS always produces minidump on exit?

Tags: qgis, qgis-2.8, minidump

QGIS 2.8.2 on windows 8.1 produces the below error every time it is closed.

Anyone have any ideas as to why or possible fixes ?[image: minidump]

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE Jay! Could be due to a number of reasons. I experienced this when I used a plugin which still retained shapefile data after I closed the project. QGIS didn't like that. Perhaps disabling plugins you don't often use?

Comment: You could also consider reinstalling QGIS, sometimes uninstalling and deleting registry keys related to QGIS can solve some problems.

Comment: I had the same problem. It was solved when I installed QGIS 2.10.1.

Answer (score 3):

in the past when I disabled my plugins, the minidump error message didn't go away

But when I just moved (or cleared) the contents of the plugin folder, that is C:\Users\Rob.qgis2\python\plugins, the minidump error stopped

then I just re-installed my plugins one by one. I have also done this to improve QGIS loading speed. Eventually too many or a particular plugin that I haven't isolated bogs my QGIS system down.